# Ionic using Adobe Flash Object

Tags: android, flash, ionic-framework

I am trying to use a flash object in an ionic app that i plan on using on android. The videos that I will be playing .swf and I am able to get them to play when using ionic serve on my local computer but when I run it on my tablet it does not even register that I am trying to play an `<object>`. I found a site that shows me how to manually install Adobe Flash but now I need to bundle that with my application. Can someone help me with either bundling or a better solution to play my videos.

Comment: Are these "videos" just vector (drawn shapes) animations? If so then consider converting swf to SVG animations (_ie:_ into Javascript shapes instead of Flash shapes). Another option is to just convert them to MP4 video format.